# Cannot create user in Couchbase Sync Gateway

Tags: rest, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have a running instance of a sync gateway which is connected with a data bucket. I configured the gateway with an initial user:

```
"firstuser": {
    "disabled": false,
    "password": "abc"
}
```

The sync gateway webview shows exactly this single user. Now I want to add another user via the REST api:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST -d '{"name":"raphi", "password":"abc"}' http://192.168.1.150:4995/_admin/db/test/_user/
```

or

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"password":"abc"}' http://192.168.1.150:4995/_admin/db/test/_user/raphi
```

The result is that no user is created, the webview still shows only one (the initial) user. Additionally,  I get a useless html-code answer:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>Couchbase Sync Gateway</title>
    <style>/* global tags */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>...</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: I just tried to use the authentication API by sending a POST with `{"name":"raphi"}` to `/test/_session/`. This also results in an HTML page response instead of [the documented JSON data](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/sync-gateway/administering-sync-gateway/authenticating-users/index.html#custom--indirect--authentication). So this seems to be a general API problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me! The URL was simply wrong: it should not contain `_admin/db/`. Therefore, the right URLs would be:

```
http://192.168.1.150:4995/test/_user/
http://192.168.1.150:4995/test/_user/raphi
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:4985/test/demo@abc.com --data '{"password":"12345678", "name":"demo@abc.com"}'
```

You can check, http://127.0.0.1:4985/_admin/db/test/users

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"name":"mohammad", "password":"123","admin_channels":["mohammad","public"]}' http://192.168.1.137:4985/grocery/_user/
```

Comment: Code-only answers are typically discouraged here. Can you edit and add some explanation?